# Ka-Binen Sänger - Joke?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

Is anyone able to explain the punchline in this anecdote for me please?

> Ein Bassist war einmal gemeinsam mit M. in Ostende, und beide
> benutzten zum Baden eine gemeinsame Kabine. In dieser Kabine begann der
> Bassist plötzlich laut zu singen. Darauf erhob M. beschwörend die
> Hände und sagte: "Um Gottes willen, hören Sie auf, ich habe es ja
> immer gewußt, daß Sie Ka-binen(ka-Bühnen-)Sänger sind.

This is exactly how it's written in the text - I'm not really clear if the portion in brackets is part of what was said or some attempt to clarify the joke?

Comment: *ka* is *kein* in southern accents, and long *ü* and long *i* sound similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some southern dialects the pronounciation of

> Kabinensänger (= singer in a cabin/cubicle/here in the sense of shower)

Is very similar to

> kein Bühnensänger (= no stage singer)

(Phonetically the 'kein' is in these dialects simplified to 'ka' and the 'ü' in 'Bühnensänger' sounds rather similar to an 'i': ka binensänger)

The joke obviously is in the latter contrasting with what they do for a living.

Comment: Warum darf man eine Biene nicht baden? Naja, es heißt ja: Bade ka Biene (Badekabine).

Comment: Thanks, so you think the bit in brackets is just a rather awkward explanation of the joke? (For reference, nowhere else in the text does the author do this...) I wasn't sure if I was missing some reference in the ka-binen-ka-bühnen sequence.

Comment: @ajor basically yes, that is it

Comment: I like how you added this answer despite mine containing the exact same information. Love it.

Comment: @ErithreusHoffing, so you are unable to see the difference in quality of the answers? That’s interesting.

Comment: Yes, I find it insulting when others post exactly the same answer and get more recognition. I am butthurt about it. See you.

Comment: So basically it's a "dad joke" in German. I'm reminded of The Mikado: "What if it should prove that, after all, I am no musician?/There! I was certain of it, directly I heard you play!"

Comment: @ErithreusHoffing I saw your answer, I saw Janka's comment. And I found both to be too brief and too brief to edit it, so I decided to elaborate slightly more on it in an own answer instead of rewriting yours. I'm sorry you feel offended (I sometimes felt the same on some other answers, here or other SE). Yet I can only invite you to better my or other answers as well. To me these situation teach me how to express myself better, find the central point of questions even behind the pure words - and / or how others read the question in ways I didn't grasp when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe ka = kein binen = Bühnen, "I knew you were not a stage singer". In some dialect.

The joke being one meaning being negated, the other not.